# How to use ARRAY contains operator with ANY

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a table where one column is array:

```
CREATE TABLE inherited_tags (
   id serial,
   tags text[]
);
```

Sample values:

```
INSERT INTO inherited_tags (tags) VALUES 
    (ARRAY['A','B','C']),  -- id: 1
    (ARRAY['D','E']),      -- id: 2
    (ARRAY['A','B']),      -- id: 3
    (ARRAY['C','D']),      -- id: 4
    (ARRAY['D','F']),      -- id: 5
    (ARRAY['A']);          -- id: 6
```

I want to find rows which *tags* column contains some subset of words inside array. For example for input:

```
ARRAY[ARRAY['A','C'], ARRAY['F'], ARRAY['E']]::text[][]
```

I want to find all rows that contain ('A' and 'C') OR ('F') OR ('E'). So for example above I should get rows with ids: 1, 2, 5.

I was hoping that I could use syntax like this:

```
SELECT * FROM inherited_tags WHERE
   tags @> ANY(ARRAY[ARRAY['A','C'], ARRAY['F'], ARRAY['E']]::text[][])
```

but I get error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text[] @> text
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM inherited_tags where tags <@ ANY(ARRAY[ARRAY['...
```

Postgres 9.6

plpgsql solution is acceptable but SQL is preferred.

DB-FIDDLE: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cKCr7Sfab6u8rqaCHhJvPk/0

Comment: PG multidimensional array support is pretty poor, you should rethink your approach to this if possible. I mean, forget about the problem you posted, just doing `SELECT ARRAY[ARRAY['A','C']::text[], ARRAY['F']::text[], ARRAY['E']::text[]]::text[][]` returns an error about matching dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the `text[]` and `text[][]` data types are internally the same data type. An array has a base type and dimensions, and the `ANY` operator will always extract the base type to compare, which will always be `text` and not `text[]`. It doesn't help that multidimensional arrays require that each subelement has the same length as every other. You can have `ARRAY[ARRAY['A','C'],ARRAY['B','N']]`, but not `ARRAY[ARRAY[2,3],ARRAY[1]]`.

**In short, there is no direct way to make that particular query work.** I tried to create a function and an operator for this as well, and that doesn't work, either, for different reasons. See how that went:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_tag_matches(
    IN leftside text[],
    IN rightside text)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$BODY$
 DECLARE rightarr text[];
BEGIN
  SELECT CAST(rightside as text[]) INTO rightarr;
  RETURN SELECT leftside @> rightarr;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;

CREATE OPERATOR public.>>(
  PROCEDURE = check_tag_matches,
  LEFTARG = text[],
  RIGHTARG = text,
  COMMUTATOR = >>);
```

Then when testing it:

```
test=# SELECT * FROM inherited_tags WHERE
   tags >> ANY(ARRAY[ARRAY['A','M'], ARRAY['F','E'], ARRAY['E','R']]::text[][]);
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "A"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT CAST(rightside as text[])"
PL/pgSQL function check_tag_matches(text[],text) line 4 at SQL statement
```

It seems that when you try using a multidimensional array like `ARRAY[ARRAY['A','M'], ARRAY['F','E'], ARRAY['E','R']]::text[][]` in `ANY()`, it iterates not over `ARRAY['A','M']`, then `ARRAY['F','E']`, then `ARRAY['E','R']`, but over `'A','M','F','E','E','R'`. The same thing happens when with `unnest`.

```
test=# SELECT unnest(ARRAY[ARRAY['A','M'], ARRAY['F','E'], ARRAY['E','R']]::text[][]);
 unnest 
--------
 A
 M
 F
 E
 E
 R
(6 rows)
```

Your remaining optiona are to define a function that will read `array_length(rightside,1)` and `array_length(rightside,2)` and use nested loops to check it all, or you can send multiple queries to get the inherited tags for each tag, or restructure your data somehow. And you can't even access the `ARRAY['A','M']` element using `rightside[1]` to iterate over it, you're forced to go to the deepest level.

Comment: Thank you for pointing fact `multidimensional arrays require that each subelement has the same length`. It shows that I cannot do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with a single condition because of the "contains A **and** C" requirement.

```
SELECT * 
FROM inherited_tags 
WHERE tags @> ARRAY['A','C']
   OR tags && array['F', 'E'];
```

`tags @> ARRAY['A','C']` selects those where `tags` contains **all** elements from `ARRAY['A','C']` and `tags && array['F', 'E']` selects those rows that contain at least one of the tags from `array['F', 'E']`

Updated DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rXsjqEN3ry67uxJtEs3GM9/0

Comment: Unfortunately, this 2 dimensional array that we use to filter rows is created from user input and your approach would require that sql is created dynamically (for diffrent input I would have to use different SQL).

Answer (score 1):

u can try

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
    tags @> ARRAY['A','C']::varchar[]
       OR
    tags @> ARRAY['E']::varchar[]
       OR
    tags @> ARRAY['F']::varchar[]
```